# ASP.NET Core - Fill a form inside a View with bound ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view, model-binding

my question is more logical than practical. So I have notifications system and everytime a notification is clicked it reroutes me to a page where I should give feedback to a user.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDljq.png)

I need the UserId inside my Feedback Page, this way I can add the new Feedback to that user.
So what I am asking is: How do I tackle this problem? Will ViewData[] solve my problem or is flawed this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rerouting to a new page, and want to pass in the user's ID, I believe you would be well off to use a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

From the link that takes you to the Feedback Page, you can use a URL like this:
https://example.com/feedback?userId=123456
or add it to however you are building your links

From the Feedback Page, you can then capture that query from the URL

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So you are saying that using query string to transfer the ID is better than using TempData or ViewData?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the data exactly? This may answer your question. Using a query string will allow you to essentially 'save' that page, so if you wanted to go directly to that user's feedback page, you can do that, and the user id will be passed within that query string.

Comment: In order for me to go from notifications to feedback page and be able to submit the feedback, I need the UserId related to the User I am about to give feedback to. So all i need is to get the string UserId from the Notification page to the feedback View Page.

Comment: Okay, I guess I need more context. You get a notification for a user, and you want to submit feedback for the user, I understand that part. Are you ever going to have a case where you submit additional feedback for the user or is this also specific to what you are getting the notification for? Do you ever need to get back to edit that feedback without using the notifications? Do you want to save that feedback URL for that specific user for any reason?

Comment: No, it goes like that. I have dogsitters and owners(of dogs) and whenever an appointment between them ends - the Owner gets a notification which routes them to a page where they need to fill feedback info. But all the information about the dogsitter(like their Id) is contained inside the notification. So i need that Id onto the page where the owner fills the feedback field. That's what i need to know. How to get that Id from the notifiction onto the feedback page where owners have InputModel for the feedback.